# Django - One model divided in two forms, how can I relate the two with the ID?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Locatario model that has two main attributes: one one them concerns to the personal attributes of the person (first form - LocatarioPfForm) and the second one the details about the civil contract we have (the second form - ContratForm).

```
class LocatarioPfForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Locatario
    fields = ['unidade', 'locatario_nome', 'locatario_genero', 'locatario_rg', 'locatario_cpf', 'locatario_estado_civil', 'locatario_bens', 'locatario_conjuge', 'fiador_boolean', 'fiador_genero', 'fiador_nome', 'fiador_rg', 'fiador_cpf', 'fiador_estado_civil', 'fiador_bens', 'fiador_conjuge']
```

```
class ContratoForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Locatario
    fields = ['data_de_inicio', 'data_de_termino', 'valor_bruto', 'valor', 'epoca_pagamento', 'vencimento', 'multa_compensatoria', 'carencia_multa', 'pdf_contrato']
    widgets = {
      'data_de_inicio': DateInput(),
      'data_de_termino': DateInput(),
      'carencia_multa': DateInput(),
    }
    help_texts = {
      'multa_compensatoria': '<span class="text-muted">O Valor da multa pode ser tanto em número absoluto, como aluguéis inteiros (ex: 1300 ou 3900), ou pode ser em porcentagem. No último caso, coloca-se a porcentagem em números decimais. 10% é 0.10, por exemplo.</span>',
    }
```

In views.py, I created two views to reference the two forms:

```
def pessoaFisicaCadastro(request, pk):
  loc = locatario_pk(pk)
  form = LocatarioPfForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LocatarioPfForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     return redirect('contrato-cadastro', pk=pk)


  context = {
    'form': form,
```

```
def contratoCadastro(request):
  c_form = ContratoForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    c_form = ContratoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if c_form.is_valid():
      c_form.save()
      return redirect('condominio')

  context = {
    'c_form': c_form,
  }
  return render (request, 'cadastro/contrato.html', context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('cadastro/pessoafisica', 
      views.pessoaFisicaCadastro, 
      name='pessoafisica-cadastro'),
path('cadastro/<int:pk>/contrato', 
      views.contratoCadastro, 
      name='contrato-cadastro'),
```

This is what I want to do: I have a template (generate.html) that loads LocatarioPfForm. In this same template, there is a button that redirects to another template, contrato.html, which loads ContratoForm. When I save the two, however, I create two distinct objects in the database.

How can I relate the two forms to the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

You pass the instance to the form with the `instance=…` parameter:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def contratoCadastro(request, pk):
    locatario = get_object_or_404(Locatario, pk=pk)
    c_form = ContratoForm(instance=locatario)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_form = ContratoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=locatario)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            c_form.save()
            return redirect('condominio')

    context = {
        'c_form': c_form,
    }
    return render (request, 'cadastro/contrato.html', context)
```